# Need to use "configure --prefix" in order to "make install"

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf, prefix

I need to use "configure --prefix" in order to "make install" in a particular location. Only a makefile is provided, not a configure file. I have never used autoconf or created a configure script myself. I found a guide [here](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/), but got lost at the 5th step involving target binaries etc. Is there any way to make install in the location I need it to be in without creating a configure file. If not, is there any easy way (or a simple guide/tutorial) to make a configure file?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear to me.  Are you trying to create a `configure` for a package you authored, or are you trying to install some (unnamed) package that does not follow the [GNU Build System](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/automake/manual/html_node/GNU-Build-System.html) conventions?  I'm assuming the latter.

If the package you are trying to install does not come with a `configure` file, there is no point in trying to run `./configure`, and I would advice against building one unless you are very familiar with that package (and in that case you would know how to install it).

Without knowing what package it is, I would suggest the following course of actions:

1. Search this package's README files or web pages for instructions about installation.
2. Look into the `Makefile`.  Maybe you will find a simple `install` rule and all you have to do is edit that rule or some variable to point to the desired location.  Some package are so simple they don't even come with an installation rule: for instance they maybe build a binary, and you are expected to copy that binary wherever you want by your self.
3. Contact the author(s) of that package.